# How to push items into array in php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, laravel, elasticsearch

I am using Laravel with ES and trying to build a dynamic query.

But the following doesnt work:

```
$query[] = ['term' => ['city' => 1]];
$query[] = ['term' => ['state' => 2]];
$query[] = ['range' => ['price' => ['lte' => 2]]];


$asd = ['filtered' => [
        'query' => [
            'match' => ['title' => Input::get('query')]
        ],
        'filter'=> [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => [
                    ['term' => [ 'is_active' =>  1] ],
                    [ 'range' => [
                        'end_date' => [
                            'from' => 'now'
                        ]
                    ]
                    ],
                    $query
                ]
            ]
        ],
    ],];


echo json_encode($asd);
```

This will append $query[] wrong into $asd, like:

```
{"term":{"is_active":1}},
{"range":{"end_date":{"from":"now"}}},
[
{"term":{"city":1}},
{"term":{"state":2}},
{"range":{"price":{"lte":2}}}
]
```

How I would like to append it is:

```
{"term":{"is_active":1}},
{"range":{"end_date":{"from":"now"}}},
{"term":{"city":1}},
{"term":{"state":2}},
{"range":{"price":{"lte":2}}}
```

without the [] around it.

**Solved**:

```
$asd = ['filtered' => [
        'query' => [
            'match' => ['title' => Input::get('query')]
        ],
        'filter'=> [
            'bool' => [
                'must' => 
                    $query

            ]
        ],
    ],];
```

Comment: The `[]` indicates that the objects are in an array. Without the brackets, it would not be legal json.

Comment: @Jite The [] shouldnt be in it, ES will return an error if I send that query. Check my update.

Comment: What is ES? And why would it ask for none-valid json?

Comment: Elasticsearch https://www.elastic.co/ , is there any way to convert my query to look like the 2nd one? Thanks

Comment: I'm quite sure that Elastic search would not ask you for invalid json. What error/s are you getting? Could it be that each object should be sent as a separate request?

Comment: @Jite I will try to work out my logs. But if I hard code the query without making it dynamic by adding query[] it works fine. Eg: writing ['term' => ['city' => 1]] myself into it. I uploaded a screenshot of the output

Comment: @Jite Thanks for your help. But I worked ut out. See my update, that will result in it not adding an extra [] around it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid json string always consist of a single object or an array of objects.
The string you are asking for is not legal json, it would not be possible to parse.

Json with a single object looks like this:

```
{ // Object start.
  "property": "value" // Where value could be a object or array or whatever.
} // Object end.
```

And if an array:

```
[ // Array start.
  "Array value" // which could be an object or another array or whatever.
] // Array end.
```

When you convert your PHP array containing associative arrays, it will be converted into a string containing a array of objects.

You could always remove the `[]` from the string if you wish it to look like you described, but it will not be valid json.

---

Edit:

An elastic query looks basically like this:

```
{ 
    "query": {
        "term": { data ... }
    }
}
```

I'm guessing that what you want/need to do is to create the php array like this:

```
$query = [
    'query' => [
        'term' => [
            'state' => 2
            'city' => 1
        ],
        'range' => [
            'price' => [
                'lte' => 2
            ]
        ]
    ]
]
```

Which would result in a JSON string that looks like this:

```
{ 
    "query": 
    { 
        "term": 
        { 
            "state": 2,
            "city": 1
        },
        "range": 
        {
            "lte": 2
        }
    } 

}
```